# Featured Image inserted through custom query, does not show up

Tags: post-thumbnails, migration

I need to transfer all my records from OpenCart to WooCommerce powered WordPress site. I used custom query to insert the image urls from opencart db to wp_posts as attachment and guid as the URL of the image, along with post_parent being the product id for that particular image. While the listings show in Media, it still does not load show images and also does not appear on Featured Image box of related products. But if I copy the url from Media manager and open it in new tab. The image shows up just fine. What could be the reason?

Also is there any other way to transfer OpenCart data to WooCommerce? Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: In the media library, is the image being shown as "attached" to a `post/post_id`?

Comment: to make an image appear as a featured image for a post, you have to add a meta key named `_thumbnail_id` with the image's ID.

Comment: @userabuser it shows the product name under Uploaded to Section.

Comment: @Milo will try that. but since i saw only two postmeta added to other featured images, I did only that.

Comment: @Milo I tried what you said, but still it does not show up

Comment: the meta key has to be associated to the post you want the featured image assigned to. post the code you've used to do all of this, otherwise you're only going to get guesses as to what your problem may be.

Comment: I am sorry for the incomplete question. Also I managed to solve it. It was missing "_wp_attachment_metadata"  post meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for the incomplete question. Also I managed to solve it. It was missing "_wp_attachment_metadata" post meta.